# How to encourage my Alocasia xAmazonica to make new offsets?

Tags: houseplants, roots, propagation, aroid, alocasia

My *Alocasia xAmazonica* has gone through its second winter and is expected to break dormancy soon.
It has got many new leaves throughout latest growth season, but at the moment just three remained.
I also noticed its tuber has grown partially above the soil surface. Should I plant it deeper during the growth season? Will this encourage my *Alocasia* to offset? I am planning on dividing the tuber.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Production of offsets is a normal process which happens when the mother plant is growing vigorously and has proceeded beyond the juvenile stage and has progressed to flowering and a degree of maturity. So all you really have to do is keep it growing vigorously, giving it space to grow and flourish.

As with other plants that produce underground storage organs there is a risk that these corms, tubers and other thickened roots will displace soil and even though you appear to have lots of soil available there might be much less. Learn how to turn the plant out of its pot so that you can visually examine that the root ball is not too crowded. This will allow the whole plant to be more vigorous and produce the offsets you seek.